# Why did the show pause in episode 1?

Tags: konosuba

In Episode 1 of Konosuba the anime pauses for a moment, just like in a video game. However, this is meant to be an alternate *real* world.

[image: -Pause- Press Start Button Konosuba]

Why did the show pause like this?

Comment: Was it in the middle of the episode? Could have been an advertisement break that you don't see in online episodes.

Comment: @Hakase Yes, it was. I wonder if thats possibly what happened then... That would make a lot of sense

Comment: Yes, that was in fact the mid-episode advertisement break.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For people watching via an online stream or disk, this made a little less sense as it pauses and then unpauses and it may be a little difficult to understand what happened. However, for viewers watching the broadcast on television it made more sense because this screen was placed just before and after the commercial break. It's merely the art used to transition to commercial.

Answer (score 0):

It was meant to be funny. Not an advertisement. The game is heavily based off RPG Video Games and throwing in a "Pause" was just to add to the humor. This was literally my favorite (and most memorable) addition to the episode.

Comment: They weren't saying it was an advertisement. This is the screen they showed when they went to commercial break when the show aired on live TV